# Linq, lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, ado.net

I have a database with a "many to many"-relationship. And I'm trying with lambda and linq to remove an entry in the Many-to-many table.

I have one Ado-entity called `Book` and another called `Author`.
Book contains the navigation property `Authors` and `Author` contains the property `Books`.

Now I want to remove a book from my DB. To do this I have to remove it's foreign-keys in the `AuthorBooks`-table, this is however proving to be difficult.

This is my syntax at the time:

```
var a = db.db.Authors.Select(c => db.db.Authors.Where(c.Books.Contains(book));
```

This is not accepted by Visual studio and I don't know how to get to where I want.
Thanks in advance!

Pictures from my errors:

---

http://olofd.dyndns.org:8887/pic1.PNG

---

http://olofd.dyndns.org:8887/pic2.PNG

---

http://olofd.dyndns.org:8887/pic3.PNG

Comment: Out of curiosity why isn't this a `Book`, `Author`, `BookAuthor` model? (with a joining independent table)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should fix it:

```
book = db.Books.Single(b => b.BookId == book.BookId);
 var bookCopies = db.BookCopies.Where(c => c.BookId == book.BookId).ToList();

 foreach (BookCopy c in bookCopies)
 {
     db.BookCopies.DeleteObject(c);
 }

 var authors = db.Authors.Include("Books").Where(author => author.Books.Any(b => b.BookId == book.BookId)).ToList();

 foreach (Author a in authors)
 {
     a.Books.Remove(book);
 }

 db.DeleteObject(book);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

The reason you got the error was because you didn't include the Books relationship when loading the authors. Because of this you looped trough an author collection where each author had zero books. Removing the book with a.Books.Remove(book) didn't do anything.

You could see that this happened when you checked the db.ObjectStatemanger. You where deleting entities but nothing showed up in the state manager.

You also need to add a ToList() to the queries. Otherwhise you will be deleting entities from the same collection as you are iterating and this will throw an exception.

Comment: Ah! Thanks a bunch! With your code I'm left with only one problem. Bookcopies are still referred to in Loans. So I can't delete a book that has a loan. I tried to add this loop, without luck, any ideas?:               foreach (BookCopy bookcopy in bookCopies)
            {
              var loansWithBook = bookcopy.Loans.Where(loan => loan.BookCopyID == bookcopy.BookCopiesID);
                foreach (Loan e in loansWithBook)
                {
                    db.db.Loans.DeleteObject(e);
                }
            }

Comment: Got it working by adding a .ToList(); in the foreachloop. This deleted a "Collection was modified" exception. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're specifying too many things too many times. I'd expect it to look something like:

```
var authors = db.Authors.Where(author => author.Books.Contains(book));
```

To be honest, I would *hope* that when you deleted the entity, LINQ would already remove the foreign key relationships for you - are you sure it doesn't?

Comment: Thanks! that works great but how do i remove the book after this. I'm trying to loop though it with a foreach but how do I remove the specified book. Sorry that my question did not ask that at first, this is what i want to do after this, but it's not working:             foreach (Author a in authors)
            {
                a.Books.Remove(book);
            }

Comment: No, it does not remove the relationship. it gives me this exception: The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Comment: @ObjectiveCoder: When you say "it gives me this exception" - when you do what? When you just try to remove the book itself? If you could show us what the relations look like in the generated LINQ, and what you've tried and the results, that would be useful. (Edit this into the question rather than adding comments.)

Comment: Did you get what you requested Jon?

Comment: @ObjectiveCoder: Posting the text would have been more useful than everyone having to squint at screenshots, but yes, we can see now. Why do you need to refer to `db.db` everywhere, by the way? That doesn't look good. You also haven't shown what happens if you just try to call `DeleteObject` on the `Book` itself.